# In[*] and Out[*] numbers increase all the time

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm on mac 10.7, in ipython notebook, every time I run cell>Run All; numbers of In's and Out's increase, is there any way to have notebook starting at In[1] at the very beginning, by the way when I insert a cell in between other two the In[*] number runs consecutively. Please help.

Comment: Restart your kernel and run all.

Comment: This is a feature, not a bug.